# How to locate an object in the Layers panel with a shortcut?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shortcuts

In my artboard, I have tons of objects. I'd like to focus it on Layers panel with some mouse/keyboard shortcut or combination.

Like in Photoshop, I can easily <kbd>right click</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> to focus the layer on the Layer Panel.

Is it possible on Illustrator? I know I can open the Layer menu and click "Locate Object", but that's not a great deal with fast operations.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I entirely understand you question, but I'll take a guess.

Open the layers panel, expand the layers so you can find all the objects within, the find the layer or object you want and select it as shown below. The object or layer will be selected on the artboard.

[image]

Note: This also works in reverse, select the object on the artboard, and the relevant object will be shown in the layers panel.

**Edit further to comments:**

Although Locate Object has no shortcut key, it is possible to record the Locate Object as an action and assign a hotkey to the run the action. I tested this and it seems to work. Hopefully it's what you are looking for.  I assigned Ctrl+F2 as the hotkey. Remember if you work on a laptop you may also need to hold down the Fn key to access the F keys.

[image]

Comment: I want the "reverse", but it works only for "selection", not focus. If I have 1000 layers, I need to scroll until I found it... which is not good.

Comment: @markzzz see edit I made to the answer

Comment: But I need to locate the object on Layer Panel, not on the artboard. Artboard is the place when I select the object, so I'm seeing it :) Its the other parts that's art to locate...

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. Isn't that what my answer already shows? Select an object and it's indicated in the layers panel? Perhaps consider posting some screen shots to demonstrate what you are trying to do or what is failing.

Comment: Create 100 objects random, select one of them from the artboard (with mouse). Can you see it on the Layer panel? Yes if you are lucky. Else, you need to scroll the Layer Panel's layer until you see the selected one. That's what I need: to locate immediatly the object selected on the artboard...

Comment: @markzzz OK, see my edit again. Hopefully this will work for you now.

Answer (score 0):

There is a "Locate Object" feature in the Layer Panel, which will locate and focus the layer of selected object, but seems it cannot be assigned a shortcut to it.

You can find it as a button in Layer Panel,...

[image]

...or in the Layer Panel menus.

[image]

Hope this helps!